# Redis StackExchange ConnectionMultiplexer connection event fire twice

Tags: c#, stackexchange.redis, eventhandler

I am using [Redis StackExchange ConnectionMultiplexer](https://stackexchange.github.io/StackExchange.Redis/) to establish a connection with the server. 
I want to log the connection activity changes when the connection is disconnected/restored. But somehow the event is fire twice when is triggered which produces duplicated messages into my log.

```
    ConnectionMultiplexer connection = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(new ConfigurationOptions()
    {
        EndPoints = { "localhost" },
        AbortOnConnectFail = false
    });            

    connection.ConnectionFailed += (sender, args) =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Connection failed ");
    };

    connection.ConnectionRestored += (sender, args) =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Connection restored "); 
    };
```

My question is

1. Why is the [ConnectionFailed](https://stackexchange.github.io/StackExchange.Redis/Events) & [ConnectionRestored](https://stackexchange.github.io/StackExchange.Redis/Events) events fire twice when trigger?
2. How can I prevent the event being fire twice?